# Contar quantidade de ocorrências de um número

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

*Programa que tenha apenas uma função, além do programa principal, que receberá como parâmetros um número inteiro x, uma sequência de inteiros L e um natural n, que representam um item x que deve ter quantificada suas ocorrências na sequência L de tamanho n.*

*A função deverá devolver um valor natural indicando a quantidade de ocorrências de x em L.*

**Entrada:**

(a) a primeira linha da entrada contém o item procurado x;

(b) a segunda linha da entrada contém o tamanho n da sequência;

(c) as próximas n linhas representam os itens que compõem a sequência.

```
7
6
70
71
72
73
7
54
```

**Saída:**

(a) o programa principal deverá imprimir um valor natural indicando a quantidade de ocorrências de x em L de acordo com o valor devolvido pela função.

```
1
```

**Código criado até então:**

```
X = input()
N = int(input())
L = [0]
Quantidade = 0

for i in range(len(L),N):
    if X [i]==X:
        Quantidade += 1
    Novo = input()
    L.insert(0,Novo)
print(Quantidade)
```

Não estou entendo muito bem a implementação desse programa em lista, o código acima não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa criar essa lista `L`, basta ler os números e ver se são iguais ao primeiro número lido:

```
x = int(input())
n = int(input())
qtd = 0
for _ in range(n):
    if int(input()) == x:
        qtd += 1
print(qtd)
```

Usar `range(n)` faz com que o loop itere `n` vezes, e na variável do `for` usei `_`, que é uma convenção do Python para indicar que não vou usar esta variável no loop (pois só quero iterar `n` vezes).

A lista `L` era desnecessária e só estava confundindo o algoritmo.

Tanto que o enunciado não diz claramente que é para armazenar os valores em uma lista, mas [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/451130/contar-quantidade-de-ocorr%C3%AAncias-de-um-n%C3%BAmero/451135?noredirect=1#comment863337_451135) foi dito que é, então nesse caso ficaria:

```
valores = []
for _ in range(n): # guarda os valores lidos na lista
    valores.append(int(input()))

qtd = 0
for num in valores: # percorre a lista e verifica quais são iguais a x
    if num == x:
        qtd += 1
```

Repare que a lista começa vazia (você inicalizou ela com um elemento - o zero - o que não faz sentido, ela deve guardar apenas o que for lido).

---

Entendo que por ser um exercício, *provavelmente* querem que você faça a contagem manualmente em um *loop*. Mas ela também pode ser feita diretamente, pois listas possuem o método `count`, que já faz isso:

```
qtd = valores.count(x)
```

O método `count` serve para encontrar a quantidade de ocorrências de um único elemento. Mas se quiser a contagem de todos os elementos (quantas vezes cada um aparece), ele não é bom, pois para cada elemento ele percorre toda a lista novamente. Se quiser a contagem de todos, o melhor é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(valores)
print(c[x]) # quantidade de vezes que "x" ocorre em "valores"
```

O `Counter` é um dicionário que conterá, para cada elemento da lista, a quantidade que cada um ocorre. Para obter a quantidade de um elemento em particular, basta usar o elemento como chave, conforme exemplo acima.

Comment: É que na verdade eu gostaria de fazer da seguinte forma, os números que forem digitados pelo usuário dentro desse laço for, fossem armazenados em uma lista, após eles estarem na lista, por exemplo: [70,71,72,73,7,54], localizar quantas vezes o número "7" ocorre dentro dessa lista.

Comment: Resumindo, após o usuário inserir os valores "X e N" todos os valores digitados dentro do laço for, pelo usuário, seriam inseridos em uma lista, após a inserção, haveria a localização de quantas vezes o número "X" do início do programa ocorre na lista criada.

Comment: @CódigoSimples Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado! Suas explicações me ajudaram muito a entender melhor o funcionamento das lista.